# Selenium GRID Test execution

Tags: java, selenium, grid

I am trying hard to run my Selenium Test not local but in a grid.
I thought I am doing good but I don´t get it to run. 
HUB and NODE are Up and running(started with CMD) and I am using the right IP adresses.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong! Do you think it maybe could be a problem with a proxy?

Greetings Arno (student from Germany)

```
// Import all the stuff I need


public class MpreisScreenshot_ID {

private String baseUrl;

  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() throws Exception {


    String requiredBrowser = "firefox";


    }
    //the "if" underneath is just for a selection (to make it better to read 
   // I  deleted the others)

     if (requiredBrowser == "firefox")
    {  
    DesiredCapabilities capabilityFirefox = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilityFirefox.setBrowserName("firefox");
        capabilityFirefox.setVersion("54");
        WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new 
URL("http://***.***.***.**:4445/grid/register"),capabilityFirefox); 
    } 




    baseUrl = "http://*****/****";
  //  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

WebDriver driver;


@Test
public void captureScreenshot() throws Exception 
{ 
//Start of Selenium test

// Maximize the browser

driver.manage().window().maximize();

// deleted all the steps




 @AfterMethod
 public void tearDown(ITestResult result)
 {

 // Test failing or Passing?
 if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus())
 { 
try 
{
// Create reference of TakesScreenshot



TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss");
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
String uhrzeit= sdf.format(timestamp);
// Call method to capture screenshot
File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("D:\\DATA\\Selenium\\TestNG-
 Screenshots\\"+result.getName()+uhrzeit+".png"));

System.out.println("Screenshot taken");

} 
catch (Exception e)
{

System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "+e.getMessage());
} 



}
// close application
driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post how you started your hub and node?

Comment: HUB: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -port 4445  
                                                                                                          
NODE: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://***.***.***.*:4445/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,version=54,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10"  Both started with the CMD. So I use the IP and the same port (4445)

Answer (score 0):

Check your url, usually the default port for the Selenium Hub is 4444, also try the following:

```
http://youripaddress:4444/wd/hub/
```